# how to predict accurately calculate progress during streaming download

Tags: python, qt, progress-bar, python-requests

I am trying to use a streaming post request to download files from my online database while providing an accurate indication of the relative download progress to drive a progress bar in my QT application.

I thought I could simply compare `chunk_size` * `chunk` amount to the file size to know how much relative data I have downloaded, but it doesn't seem to work that way.
To test my understanding of chunks I set the `chunk_size` to be the same as the file size (about 9.8MB). This is my test code:

```
with closing(requests.post(ipAddress,
                           headers={'host':hostURL},
                           data=dataDict,
                           timeout=timeout,
                           stream=True)) as responseObject:
    chunkNumber = 0
    for chunk in responseObject.iter_content(chunk_size=10276044):
        print chunkNumber
        chunkNumber += 1
        content += chunk
```

I expected to only see one or two chunks, but instead I see `chunkNumber` increase to anywhere between 1600 and over 4000 when I run the test multiple times.

I am obviously misinterpreting the use of `chunk_size`, so my question is:
How can I accurately determine the relative progress of the download during the `iter_content()` loop so that I can drive a progress bar from 0 to 100%?

Cheers,
frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for my own project was to find the **length of the response and divide by 100**.

This is Python 3 code so just **remove the parentheses from the print statements** to be compatible with 2.

```
f = open(title, 'wb')
response = requests.get(url, params=query, headers=HDR, stream=True)
size = int(response.headers.get('content-length'))
CHUNK = size//100 # size for a percentage point
if CHUNK > 1000000: # place chunk cap on >1MB files
    CHUNK = 100000 # 0.1MB
print(size, 'bytes')
print("Writing to file in chunks of {} bytes...".format(CHUNK))
actual = 0 # current progress
try:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK):
        if not chunk: break
        f.write(chunk)
        actual += len(chunk) # move progress bar
        percent = int((actual/size)*100)
        if 'idlelib' in sys.modules: # you can take these conditions out if you don't have windows
        #if you do then import sys, os at the start of the program
            if not(percent % 5):
                print('{}%'.format(percent), end=' ')
        else:
            os.system('title {}% {}/{}'.format(percent, actual, size))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my request response.headers.get('content-length') returns None

Comment: Your example also implies that you aren't seeing the same problem as I do. Your usage is what I was expecting to see working. However, no matter how large I set the chunk size, I get thousands of iterations, and the amount of iteration changes every time I run the same exact code, so I don't see how I can deduct indicative download progress from that.

Comment: Oops, I apologise, I missed the "actual" variable building up len(chunk), which is the actual size of the chunk. My mistake was to assume that my requested chunk_size is the actual chunk size when it's not. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @FrankRueter What is the link to your file?

Comment: You mean the file I am trying to download? It's served up by a server side php script after providing certain log in credentials. But it's resolved now as per my last comment, thanks.